# IOS:Can I get a object by restoration id in xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created many of text fields in the storyboard and register the objects to **ViewController.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *a0;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *a1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *a2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *a3;
...
```

I want to add something between the text fields such as check for the value of textfield if it is 0. Currently I have to write many if-else statements.

```
if(self.a1.text==0){
    //do something
}else if(self.a2.text==0){
    //do something
}...
```

I want to use a loop to do this thing. Can I use the restoration id to get the object of text fields? Suppose I have assigned a restoration id in ordered sequence (i.e. a0,a1,a2...)

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
     if(findViewById("a"+i).text==0){
          //do something
     }
}
```

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `tags`, or you can use a `IBOutletCollection` instead of having individual `@property` for each `UITextField`. For comparing the value to "0", do it like this:

```
[self.a1.text isEqualToString:@"0"]
```

Comment: i will suggest for IBOutletCollection. and +1 for suggesting the same.